# find records from one column in another: excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have few numbers like this in Excel:

```
            Col B       Col I
            ------------------
            104        160
            105        236
            158        342
            160        630
            250
            290
```

Both are extracted from a DB and inputted in Excel in proper Order (in their respective columns)

I see "160" of Column I is present in Col B

Can any one please give me a formula , where I need to find "the numbers present in col I is present or NOt in Col B" ?

I want result like :

```
            Col B       ColI     Col C (My result columns)
            -------------------------------
            104        160
            105        236
            158        342
            160        630        160
            250
            290
```

I have variable number of records on Col B and Column I . There are around 1K records.

```
            I have used formula: =INDEX($B$2:$B$989,MATCH($I2,$B$2:$B$989,0))
```

However, its not helping. May be highlight those in a color will help as well.Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? `COUTNIF()` should work.

Comment: I have edited my question with what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula looks good, however, to achieve the result you included, you should use it the other way around. You can also add `IFERROR()` to get rid of all that errors and leave blank cells. Check this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$20,MATCH($B2,$I$2:$I$20,0)),"")
```

Change number of rows for data in column `I`.

Comment: It looks like its only working for numeric. Is this formula will only work for Numbers? How about only alphabets or alphanumeric chars  in the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`vlookup`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE),"")
```

[image: =IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE),"")]